# Should I say "domesticable" or "domesticatable"?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, morphology

What should I say to sound better, "*domesticable*" or "*domesticatable*"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If OP is set on using a single word, [domesticable is far more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=domesticable,domesticatable,domesticability,domesticatability&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). Note that the less-common derivative *domesticability* does actually exist, but *domesticatabilty* is virtually unknown.

[image]

Personally, I'd probably just use *tameable, farmable, house-trainable,* or *capable of being domesticated*, depending on context.

Answer (score 2):

I would also go with domesticable if I were forced to use a single word. It however sounds better to use a descriptive statement.